# Variable doesn't add in React

Tags: reactjs, variables, babeljs

I want to do so when I click the button the variable 'balance' grows up by 1 and displays after the 'Balance: ' word. My code compiles, but displayed variable is at 0 even if I click my button.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addOne = this.addOne.bind(this);
  }
  addOne() {
    balance++;
  }
  render() {
    var balance = 0;
    var balanceStyle = {
       fontSize: 50,
       color: '#FF0000'
    }
    return (
       <div>
          <h1 style = {balanceStyle}>Balance: {balance}</h1>
          <button onClick={this.addOne}>+1</button>
       </div>
    );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons to it, Firstly, you define a variable in the render function and you try to increment it in the addOne function where it is not defined.

Even if you suppose that balance was available to the addOne  but defining it in the constructor  ,you are initialising it in the components render function and hence everytime the Component rerenders it will still be zero

Also directly chaging the value of the variable in this case won't rerender the component and reflect the change. You will have to make use of `forceUpdate()`

See the snippet of your question

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addOne = this.addOne.bind(this);
  }
  addOne() {
    balance++;
    console.log(balance)
  }
  render() {
    var balance = 0;
    var balanceStyle = {
       fontSize: 50,
       color: '#FF0000'
    }
    return (
       <div>
          <h1 style = {balanceStyle}>Balance: {balance}</h1>
          <button onClick={this.addOne}>+1</button>
       </div>
    );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></app>
```

Now the way to do it correctly will be to have balance as a state, so that everytime you update it, the component is rerended and the change is reflected immedialtely

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addOne = this.addOne.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        balance: 0
    }
  }
  addOne() {
       this.setState((prevState) => ({balance: prevState.balance + 1}))
  }
  render() {
    var balanceStyle = {
       fontSize: 50,
       color: '#FF0000'
    }
    return (
       <div>
          <h1 style = {balanceStyle}>Balance: {this.state.balance}</h1>
          <button onClick={this.addOne}>+1</button>
       </div>
    );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></app>
```

If you are wondering what is `this.setState((prevState) => ({balance: prevState.balance + 1}))` , read this **[documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)**

It is the right way to `setState` when you current state depends on you previous one or the  current props

Answer (score 0):

Each time you're re-rendering this component, you're creating a new balance variable that is scoped to the render method. The addOne method never have access to that value. It's actually creating a global variable, initializing it with the value undefined then adding one to it. Each click then add 1 to the value (which is always NaN).

To solve this problem, you should use state for your component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addOne = this.addOne.bind(this);
    this.state.balance = 0;
  }
  addOne() {
    this.setState({balance: this.state.balance + 1});
  }
  render() {
    var balanceStyle = {
       fontSize: 50,
       color: '#FF0000'
    }
    return (
       <div>
          <h1 style = {balanceStyle}>Balance: {this.state.balance}</h1>
          <button onClick={this.addOne}>+1</button>
       </div>
    );
 }
}
```

The code might help you: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

You should also probably read up on scoping in javascript and consider using strict mode.